# Django code not working for following scripts

Tags: django

following queries not working :

```py
data = replypost.objects.annotate(
        appreciate=Count(Case(
            When(
                review__userlikes='1', 
                then='1'
            ), 
            output_field=IntegerField()
        )), 
        varygood=Count(Case(
            When(
                review__userlikes='2', 
                then='1'
            ), 
            output_field=IntegerField()
        )),
        good=Count(Case(
            When(
                review__userlikes='3', 
                then='1'
            ), 
            output_field=IntegerField()
        ))
    )
```

Comment: What is not working? What is the expected behaviour? What is the observed behaviour? What is the error message?

Comment: Possible typo: `varygood` -> `verygood`.